# Check if-else statement in one time using JUnit testing

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

I try to test on how to get index 0 and 5 value from my file. I can get the value. But, to test the value with JUnit, i can only test if(index==0) but it did not check for (index==5).

So, how can i test both index in one time using if else ?

```
@Test
public void test(){
    for(index = 0; index<arrayList.size(); index++){
        if(index==0 && index==5){
            given()
                .header(something)
                .get(something)
                .then(something)
                .body("try", contains(arrayList.get(index).getSomething(),arrayList.get(index).getSomething()))
                .log().all()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `index==0 && index==5` some Schrodinger index?

Comment: Maybe what you want is `||` instead of `&&``

Comment: where is the *assert* here?

Comment: @RC. i have try using | |, also get an error.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Truckle i try to use assert, but not sure which part of assert should i use.

Comment: *"but not sure which part of assert should i use"* - well, it is *your* code after all and you are the only one knowing how your code should behave...

Comment: What error? Hopefully it's obvious that `index == 0 && index == 5` is nonsensical; might as well just delete the code in the `if` block.

Comment: Yeah it is nonsensical, but i need to test both index in one time. When the index go through the given(), i need both index go through it to check it in the .body("try" , containsString(index1, index2) .

Answer (score 2):

In a unit test each test method verifies a *single expectation* about the tested units behavior. 
Therefore you write different tests for different input and/or different expectations.

Also tests should not have (self written) logic.

If you need to iterate over input values you might consider Parameterized tests: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2012/12/16/writing-parameterized-tests-with-junit-rules/

Comment: is it means i cannot check two condition in one if(condition) ?

Comment: @Han *"is it means i cannot check two condition in one if(condition) ?"* it means you **should** not check more than one condition. There are rare cases where more that one *assert* per test method is adequate but as a rule of thumb you should avoid that.

Comment: Okay thanks very much for the explanations. @TimothyTruckle

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
 for(index = 0; index<arrayList.size(); index++){
    if(index==0 && index==5){
```

This says: if index is 0 **and** index is 5.

An int can't have **two** values at the same time. You probably want:

```
if(index==0 || index==5){
```

But of course: Timothy is correct, you want **one** "check" per test.

The proper solution would be: write a private helper method that takes an parameter `indexToCheckFor`, so that you can do

```
private void testForIndex(int indexToCheckFor) {
....
  if(index == indexToCheckFor) {
```

and then have two @Test methods, one calling `testForIndex(0)`, the other one calling for 5.